# Was Bugs Bunny a gay character?

Tags: looney-tunes

I remember as a child watching some cartoons of Bugs Bunny, where Bugs was dressed like a woman and/or kissing Elmer Fudd in the mouth.

Have there been any official reports regarding Bugs Bunny's sexual orientation?

Comment: Yeah, sure, why not?

Comment: **NO!** Being 'in drag' is still considered to be a funny joke. *Some Like it Hot*, is one example. *The Nutty Professor (1996)*, *Mrs. Doubtfire*, are two more. It is simply a tool of the comedy trade.

Comment: Bugs had a GF in the comics called honey bunny.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_Bunny  Lola was originally going to be honey bunny in the movie Space Jam.   Clock on the other GFs section for others.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_Bunny#Comparison_to_Bugs_Bunny.27s_other_girlfriends

Answer (score 14):

### No.

Despite some news reports about Steve Blanc, alleged son of voice actor Mel Blanc, saying [Bugs Bunny is gay](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/what-to-watch/bugs-bunny-facts-trivia/) and `What's up, Doc?` is a passphrase for a gay nightclub, it is just a joke article by [Citizen of the Month](http://www.citizenofthemonth.com/2007/10/27/fans-shocked-at-bugs-bunny-gay-revelation/).

> Note, November 2010:  This is not true.  It is a joke.  This was NOT approved by Warner Brothers.   And Mel’s son’s real name is Noel.  And just so you know — Bugs Bunny is probably my biggest literary influence.

Mel's son isn't called Steve and the voice actor does not decide the sexuality of the character, the studio (Warner Brothers) does.

Thanks to [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317/paulie-d) for the reminder, Bugs Bunny also had a girlfriend, [Lola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lola_Bunny). This seems to make it even more likely that he was not a homosexual.

[image]

I would wager that there cannot be any definitive proof, unless the studio actually states something like `He is not gay.`, but I find it very unlikely that he would be a closet homosexual in a fake relationship and in-love with a male from another race.

Comment: ohh good! Touché!

Comment: Lolo Bunny is a rather recent addition to Bug's group.  Anyway,Bugs clearly kisses Elmer to "bug", embarrass, annoy, and bully him. Early Bugs Bunny cartoons make him highly annoying and sort of a bully.  Elmer Fudd talks to Bugs and thus knows that Bugs is an intelligent being and a person, and yet continues to hunt him.  This makes Elmer very evil.  And yet the early Bugs Bunny was so annoying and bullying that one would almost root for the evil Elmer Fudd.

Comment: He can be a drag lesbian/bisexual and still love Lola that way ;)

Answer (score 8):

### There is no evidence Bugs is gay and plenty of evidence to the contrary.

The sexual orientation of a fictional character is completely up to those who have creative control over the character. Since most of those people who created Bugs Bunny are now deceased having never claimed that the character was meant to be gay, a conclusive answer is not likely to ever be available. However, there is a great deal of evidence of what those creators intended for the character's sexual orientation and it overwhelmingly points toward heterosexual.

Whenever Bugs Bunny is shown to have a genuine sexual interest, it is always with a female character (or with a decoy-type object that he perceives to be a female character). Some examples:

Cut to the last 10-15 seconds of this clip to see Bugs' encounter with Lauren Bacall...

Bugs was fooled (and attracted) by mechanical female rabbits on two occasions...

In [Bewitched Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Hazel_(Looney_Tunes)), the character Witch Hazel transforms into a female rabbit at the end and wins Bugs' affection.

On the other hand, Bugs' cross dressing was always done to fool an antagonist and kisses planted on the faces of male characters were always mocking and taunting, never depicted as a product of Bugs' desire.

While it is perhaps tempting for some people to try to make the case that a popular character from an era in which homosexuals were not represented in popular culture was secretly gay somehow, it is just wishful thinking. The overwhelming evidence points to the character being a heterosexual.

Answer (score -9):

### YES.

At least, [according to Steve Blanc](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/what-to-watch/bugs-bunny-facts-trivia/), son of Buggs Bunny creator Mel Blanc.

Steve wrote a book entitled *Bugs and Elmer: A Forbidden Love*, in which he draws upon aspects of Buggs' gender fluidity and the appearance of Homosexual parlance in Buggs Bunny cartoons to quite convincingly demonstrate a gay proclivity. He was certainly embraced by the LGBT community [as a gay icon](http://unvailed.com/2012/04/bugs-bunnymy-first-gay-icon/), and the phrase 'What's up Doc?' was famously used as the secret password for the Hammer Club on the Sunset Strip, a notorious (at the time) gay haunt.

Comment: While this was debunked in the other answer, I think it provides relevant information.     Might need to be edited as opinion, not hard evidence, but I think there's a fair answer in here.    Probably shouldn't get all these down-votes.

Comment: What is the relevant information here? The gay community’s use of the character’s image or catch phrase has no bearing at all on the character’s orientation. The only other thing in the answer is the citation of a debunked hoax.